# NullPointerException en Processing

Tags: java

En processing (librería de java) he creado una función que es el sinónimo de una "add" para un arraylist pero en un array convencional.

Esta función es muy pobre y solo funciona para un tipo de clase (solo vale para PVector, no para int, o float...).

Aún así debería funcionar, pero me sale un NullPointerException en la tercera línea (la de la variable "posArray").

Me he informado por internet y he visto que es porque posArray es un array con una longitud determinada, pero con un contenido nulo. Aún así no entiendo por qué no funciona, ya que estoy determinando el contenido de este más adelante (en el for loop).

Gracias de antemano.

```
PVector[] pushVector(PVector[] poss, PVector pos) {
  PVector[] temp = poss;
  PVector[] posArray = new PVector[poss.length + 1];
  for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    posArray[i] = temp[i];
  }
  posArray[temp.length] = pos;
  return posArray;
}
```

Comment: Asegurate de que `PVector[] posArray = new PVector[poss.length + 1];` es una coleccion con tantos items como iteraciones tiene el bucle que lo reccorre

Comment: Primero se hace un bucle con casi todas las "casillas" llenas (todas menos 1) y luego se añade el último PVector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUCIONADO

El problema no está en ese código, el problema está en que uso el código con un array que no tiene length (`PVector ejemploDeArray;`).

La solución sería empezar la variable con una longitud específica:

`PVector ejemploDeArray = new PVector[0];`